# Why some gitlab project clone with SSH do not have SSH schema?

Tags: gitlab

when I watch a tutorial:

when clone a project with SSH, it shows `git@xxx` like below:

[image]

but when I use my Gitlab in practice:
there have schema `ssh://`, what's the difference?

`ssh://git@gitlab.demo.com:222/xxx`

[image]

Comment: There is no difference in meaning (one is an SCP-style string without schema and with a colon between host and path, the other is a URL with schema and slash between host and path). You showed screenshots of two different versions of GitLab by the way (compare the design of the copy button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depend on how the custom SSH URL was set for your GitLab instance:

```
gitlab-ctl show-config | gitlab_ssh_host
```

The default one uses the [default SSH URL scheme](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-salowey-secsh-uri-00.html#sshuri), using '`/`' only.
But you can set it to a [SCP-style URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy_protocol#Secure_Copy_(remote_file_copy_program)), without ssh://, and using a '`:`' between domain and URL path.

To change it:

- Edit `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`
- Search for `gitlab_rails['gitlab_ssh_host'] = 'your.hostname.here'`
- Update the `hostname` value and run a `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` afterwards.